# netHttpBinding removed from IIS 8 Final (Windows 8 RTM)?

Tags: wcf, iis, windows-8, wcf-binding

I have a couple websites, that I have automated configuration, and deployment via scripts (So I am sure I am setting everything up the same as I was in Release Preview).

After I install IIS, and deploy my website, I get this error:

Parser Error Message: Configuration binding extension 'system.serviceModel/bindings/netHttpBinding' could not be found. Verify that this binding extension is properly registered in system.serviceModel/extensions/bindingExtensions and that it is spelled correctly.

I've tried installing on 3 different RTM machines, and haven't been able to find anything about this online. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: According to the docs, it's still supported http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.servicemodel.nethttpbinding.aspx

Answer (score 2):

try to add an httpRuntime-Element to your web.config. This sould solve your problem.

Wishes,
Fred

```
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
```